# Proof that $2^{ab} - 1$ is divisible by $2^a - 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

Could you please comment on the correctness and quality of the following proof?

I'm a bit suspicious of the line $n = ab, a = 1, r = 2^a$. Should it be $r = 2$? And are there any "off by one errors? E.g. $n = ab$ vs $n = ab -1$?

To prove:

For $a, b > 1$

$2^{ab} - 1$ is divisible by $2^a - 1$

Explanation:

$2^{ab} - 1$ can be expressed as $\sum_{i=0}^{ab-1}2^i$

Considering the formula for the sum of a geometric series
$S_n = a \frac{r^n-1}{r-1}$

with

$n = ab, a = 1, r = 2^{a}$

we have

$S_n = \frac{(2^a)^b-1}{2^a-1}$

From which it can be seen that $2^a - 1$ is indeed a factor of $2^{ab} - 1$.

$\square$

Comment: That seems good.

Comment: Now, replace $2$ with $x$ and $1$ with $y$.

Comment: In $$n = ab, a = 1, r = 2^{a}$$     There are two **distinct** $a$ variables floating around.  The $a$ in $n=ab, r=2^a$ is the $a$ from the problem statement.  The $a$ in $a=1$ is the $a$ from $S_n = a \frac{r^n-1}{r-1}$.  Needless to say, this is bad practice, since it causes confusion.  (I see this more in programming than I do in mathematics, since then $=$ is assignment rather than equality)

Comment: After some thought.  Are you *allowed* to use the geometric sum formula?  As the geometric sum formula is derived by demonstrating/proving that $(x-1)\sum x^k = x^n-1$ couldn't this proof be circular?  .... or we could simply make this a one line proof "this is simply one case of the geometric sum formula that claims $\sum_{k=0}^{b-1} 2^{ak}= \frac {2^{ab} -1}{2^a - 1}$"

Comment: The proof I know for the geometric sum formula uses $S − S·r$ and cancels out all but the first and last terms giving $S − S·r = a − ar^n$ and factorizing/rearranging.

Comment: Yes, but that proves  $(r-1)S = a(r^n -1)$.  So if $r$ is an integer and $a=1$, then $S$ is an integer and $r-1|r^n-1$ has been proven.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to be picky:

You state that $2^{ab}-1=\sum_{k=0}^{ab-1} 2^k$ but never actually use it. So leave it out; it just confuses things.

You should state explicitly that $S_n = \sum_{k=0}^{b-1} (2^a)^k$; as it is written I use confusing it with $\sum_{k=0}^{ab-1}=2^{ab}-1$ which is and entirely different completely irrelevant sum-- I was confused by the first line.

Then I'd like the, admittedly trivial but key, statement that: $S_n$ is an integer (as a finite sum of integers).

> I.E. the proof should be:  $S_n= \sum_{k=0}^{b-1} (2^a)^k$ is integer. But $S_n = \frac {(2^a)^b -1}{2^a - 1}$.  So $2^a - 1| (2^a)^b - 1= 2^{ab}-1$.

Otherwise the proof is good.

======

Although......

For the purpose of a stronger proof.

If we can prove that $x-1$ always divides $x^n - 1$ we will be done by letting $x = 2^a$ and $n = b$.

And the formula for the geometric series states precisely that:  That $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k$ which is clearly an integer is equal to $ \frac{x^n-1}{x-1}$.  So $x-1|x^n -1$.

Of course, it could be that this exercise is *expecting* you to prove the formula for a geometric series.

Which you *should* be prepared to do.

Pf:  $(x- 1)(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k) = x\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k=$

$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^{k+1} - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k=$

$\sum_{k=1}^n x^k - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k=$

$ ((\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} x^k) + x^n)- (x^0 + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} x^k)=$

$x^n - 1$.

So $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k = \frac {x^n - 1}{x-1}$.

(Assuming, of course, $x \ne 1$... Obviously if $x = 1$ then $(1-1)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 1^k= 0*n = 0 =1^n-1$ which is fairly pointless)

====

More interesting is proving that if $2^m -1$ is *not* divisible by $2^a-1$ *unless* $m$ is divisible by $a$.

Answer (score -1):

If we pick the common ratio to be $2^a$,

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{ab-1}2^i = \sum_{t=0}^{b-1}\sum_{i=0}^{a-1}2^{at+i} =\sum_{t=0}^{b-1}(2^a)^t \left(\sum_{i=0}^{a-1}2^i\right)
\end{align}

the first term is $\left(\sum_{i=0}^{a-1}2^i\right)$ and we have $b$ terms in total.

That is $$2^{ab}-1=\sum_{t=0}^{b-1}(2^a)^t \left(2^a-1\right)$$

$$\frac{2^{ab}-1}{2^a-1}=\sum_{t=0}^{b-1}(2^a)^t$$

Hence $2^a-1 | 2^{ab}-1$

I usually prove it in the following way:

- $x^b-1$ is clearly divisible by $x-1$ since $1^b-1=0$.
- Now, we just have to let $x=2^a$